# How do I disable fields for a user account?

Tags: users

The site I am developing has 2 type of profiles: the main account, and the alternative account associated with it. The alternative user gets blog posts, forum posts, under its own name. "He-man" and "Frodo" could be two examples.

The main accounts have signature, and image fields that never apply to them because the system always defaults to the alternative account for these things.

Since alternative accounts, and the main accounts both have different roles/permissions, how can I hide these fields using permissions?

I see that http://drupal.org/project/user_picture_field can be used to hide the picture field by setting permissions. How can I hide more than just the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module you can hide fields per role.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.
>
> #### Features
>
> - Enable field permissions on any entity, not just nodes.
> - Role-based field permissions allowing different viewing patterned based on what access the user has.
> - Author-level permissions allow viewing and editing of fields based on who the entity owner is.
> - Permissions for each field are not enabled by default. Instead, administrators can enable these permissions explicitly for the fields where this feature is needed.